# How to read line in python using defaultdict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that searches for an ID name and reads tokens after it. But I want to know if there is a way to read and print out the whole line that contains that ID name as well.

Here is what I have so far:

```
lookup = defaultdict(list)
wholelookup =defaultdict(list)
mydata = open('summaryfile.txt')

for line in csv.reader(mydata, delimiter='\t'):
    code = re.match('[a-z](\d+)[a-z]', line[-1], re.I)
    if code: 
        lookup[line[-2]].append(code.group(1))
        wholelookup[line[-2]].append(code.group(0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code calls `csv.reader()` which will return a parsed version of the whole line.  In my test, this returns a list of values.  If this list of values will do for the "whole line" then you can save that.

You have a line where you append something called `wholelookup`.  I think you want to just save `line` there instead of `code.group(0)`.  `code.group(0)` returns everything matched by the regular expression, and this would be identical to `line[-1]`.

So maybe put this line in your code:

```
wholelookup[line[-2]].append(line)
```

Or maybe you need to join together the values from `line` to make a single string:

```
s = ' '.join(line)
wholelookup[line[-2]].append(s)
```

If you want the whole line, not the parsed version, then do something like this:

```
lookup = defaultdict(list)
wholelookup = defaultdict(list)
pat = re.compile('[a-z](\d+)[a-z]', re.I)

with open('summaryfile.txt') as mydata:
    for s_line in mydata:
        values = s_line.split('\t')
        code = re.match(pat, values[-1])
        if code: 
            lookup[values[-2]].append(code.group(1))
            wholelookup[values[-2]].append(s_line)
```

This example pre-compiles the pattern for the slight speed advantage.

Comment: is there a way that i can get both the parsed version and whole line version as two variable?

Comment: i also try your code the third chunk it say line is not defined

Comment: There was a typo in my code.  That should have been `s_line.split()`... I fixed it.

Comment: In the above example, the whole line version is the variable `s_line` and the parsed version is the variable `values`.  Instead of having the `csv` module split up the input line, we just call `s_line.split('\t')` to split the line up ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory, the easiest way is to simply save the lines in another defaultdict:

```
wholeline = defaultdict(list)
...
idname = line[-2]
wholeline[idname].append(line)
```

Comment: that doesn't work.. it give me weird result: <type 'list'>.... could you please show me how you would put it in my code pls?